# How to play mp3 files in raw folder with different language?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-mediaplayer, android-resources

I have some mp3 files in raw folder and I store them in Room database as resource path (R.raw.music for example) and I localized the raw folder. I want to get the localized mp3 file from a selected language. Here is how I achieved to get the localized String

```
fun getLocaleStringResource(requestedLocale:Locale,resId:Int,context: Context) :String{
val result:String
val config = Configuration(context.resources.configuration)
config.setLocale(requestedLocale)
result= context.createConfigurationContext(config).getText(resId).toString()
return result}
```

Is there any way to get the raw files in a certain language? [image]

Answer (score 0):

1. create folder for different languages
2. save audio files with same names
3. play with media player

> MediaPlayer p1=new MediaPlayer(this,R.raw.sample)

audio will be played according selected language

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I am using Room library to get data from Raw sources. Sorry, I forgot to mention.